# Cтранности с java дополнительными библиотеками (Intellij Idea)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Скачал из интернета дополнительную библиотеку java, подключил - вроде ничего так себе, хорошо работает. Но заметил, что в jar архиве, все нужные файлы - это не java файлы, в смысле не имеют расширение .java а имеют расширение .class. Вот решил, за интерес попробовать заменить все эти .class на .java файлы. Ну как сделал?

1) Сделал копию jar архива,
2) Взял каждый отдельный .class этого архива,
3) Открыл его декомпилированный текст через Intellij,
4) Создал отдельный класс в случайной папке своего проекта, 
5) Заполнил его соответствующим кодом через ctrl+c и ctrl+v.
6) Полученный класс с расширением .java переместил в этот jar архив,
7) и так для каждого .class -а,
8) закрыл Intellij
9) переместил оригинальный jar архив в спец папку,
10) вместо него в данное место переместил отредактированный jar архив, который уже вместо файлов компиляции содержит чисто .java файлы

На мое удивление, начался бардак, по каким то загадочным причинам - импортированные от этого архива классы - не распознавались Intellij, и даже имя импорта, красной линией подчеркнулся, и говорилось, что название пакета "does not correspond to the file path" IDE предложил если не ошибаюсь -  переместить пакет куда то, нажал на предложение и вышло сообщение, что класс с данным именем в предложенном месте уже существует... кратко говоря запутался. Что тут вообще творится?

И так мой вопрос:

Почему при таком "лайфхаке" появляется такая проблема?

Стандартная библиотека вроде не содержит .class файлы а только .java.  Хотя как я заметил, стандартная библиотека хранится не в архиве jar, а в архиве zip по имени "src"... кстати за интерес решил, в копию этого zip-а переместить те классы, которые я заменил c .class на ․java - тоже не помогло... пришлось заменить обратно оригинальные архивные файлы.

Comment: В гугл. Не люблю так отвечать, но блин, просто надо загуглить что за формат первого файла и что за второй

Answer (score 0):

Не удивительно что среда разработки начала ругаться . 
сlass  - это файл, содержащий байт-код Java.

.java файл - это текстовый файл содержащий 
исходный код программы

Следовательно .java файл никак не может заменить .class файл

Comment: Отличия между .java и .class мне известны а непонятно вот что - почему стандартная библиотека работает с .java , в смысле без прямого запроса на байт код, а дополнительная библиотека работает совсем по другому, в смысле хочет .class. К тому же простые написанные мною классы тоже являются .java и ничего - вроде импортировать без проблема получается. Возможно что то я не замечаю или не в курсе но все же, выше написал причины моего непонимания.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan, виртуальная машина Java не может исполнять текстовые файлы, поэтому в jar нужно класть готовые бинарные файлы class.

Comment: Ладно, допустим - но как тогда работает стандартная библиотека, если там расширение классов .java а не .class? Или для стандартной библиотеки сделали какой то лайфхак, о котором я пока что нигде не встретил/не прочитал... ?